# Why does PyCharm can't recognize certain python libraries correctly?

Tags: python, pycharm, distutils

For example, this line of code:

```
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
```

I can import it correctly from a terminal python interpreter, but in PyCharm, it displays a red flag on 'build_ext', which says 'can't find reference 'build_ext' in 'build_ext.pyi'.

Why is that?

Comment: Did you correctly [configure the interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)?

Comment: Works fine for me with PyCharm 2020.3 and Python 3.8.6.

Comment: Yes, My interpeter is Python 3.7.10.

Answer (score 0):

check the version of the `distutils` by `print(distutils.__version__)` in the terminal.
And install that version of the `distutils` in your python environment. `pip install distutils==version`
*this seems like a version mismatch. so, some functions in the library will change or obsolete.*